# How can I bind the element ID for an Ember View?

Tags: ember.js

My model "content.id" contains a string, e,g "123":

```
{{view Em.TextArea idBinding="content.id"}}
```

Instead of just setting the id of this view to "123", I'd like it to be "message-123", basically customizing the string being used. Sadly, Ember does not allow bindings to be functions, which would solve my problem (I could define such a function on the controller).

What's the best way to achieve this?

Comment: The `id` of an `Ember.View` should not be changed after it has been created, see corresponding [code][1]. By using a binding you *could* change the `id`/`elementId` and then an error would be thrown. So my question here is why you'd want to use the `id`. What is your use case? Can you solve your problem by using a custom CSS class?

  [1]: https://github.com/emberjs/ember.js/blob/991689c321b03879148a815c1119e44e45fcc322/packages/ember-views/lib/views/view.js#L1568-1583

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could define a **computed property** in the controller (or elsewhere):

**The controller**

```
MyApp.ApplicationController = Ember.Controller.extend({
  content: "a-content",

  editedContent: function() {
      return "message-" + this.get('content');
  }.property('content')
});
```

**The view**

```
MyApp.FooView = Ember.View.extend({
    tagName: 'p'
});
```

**The template** (where content is a `String`, here)

```
{{#view MyApp.FooView elementIdBinding="editedContent"}}
    {{content}}
{{/view}}
```

And the [JSFiddle is here](http://jsfiddle.net/eLKwT/1/).

**EDIT**

> How can the view see the property `editedContent` since it belongs on the `ApplicationController` controller?

The router, after started, automatically render the `ApplicationView`, or its template when there is no `ApplicationView` defined. If you want more detail, I suggest you to read the Ember guide: [Understanding the Ember.js Router: A Primer](http://emberjs.com/guides/router_primer/).

And `{{editedContent}}` directly get the controller `editedContent` property, because the **default view context** is its controller, as you can read in [Ember Blog - 1.0 Prerelease](http://emberjs.com/blog/2012/08/03/ember-1-0-prerelease/):

> The `{{#view}}` helper no longer changes the context, instead maintaining the parent context by default. Alternatively, we will use the controller property if provided. You may also choose to directly override the context property. The order is as follows:
>
> - Specified controller
> - Supplied context (usually by Handlebars)
> - parentView's context (for a child of a ContainerView)

Comment: Actually, I have a question: how can the view see the property `editedContent` since it belongs on the `ApplicationController` controller?

Comment: Thanks for the clarification. For some reason, I was under the impression that routers were deprecated, so I never bothered reading much about them, but it looks like they are actually becoming a central piece of Ember 1.0. Off to read the articles, thanks!

Comment: Router is definitely not deprecated, but its interface will change a little to be more "user-friendly". For example, @tomdale made a draft: https://gist.github.com/3981133